# How to get next ID on next page PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to read the different ID on different page, by using the prev/next button.

If I click next button, I want to get the next ID, if I click previous button, it will back to the previous ID. Following is what I want.

Example:

1. testnext_pre1.php?**id=1**&page=1
2. testnext_pre1.php?**id=2**&page=2
3. testnext_pre1.php?**id=5**&page=3

Here is my problem. As you can see, I get the same ID on every page because of my code. How to get the correct ID for the page?

[image]
[image]
Please take note: the IDs are not increase by sequence, as some contents might be deleted. So I don't want the answer something like "+1".

```
$rowsPerPage = 1;

if(isset($_GET['page']))
{
    $pageNum= $_GET['page'];
}
else
{
    $pageNum = 1;
}

// preceding rows
$previousRows =($pageNum - 1) * $rowsPerPage;

$query = "SELECT * FROM news LIMIT $previousRows, $rowsPerPage";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error couldn\'t get the data').mysql_error();

    echo "<table border=1>\n";
    echo "<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Password</th><th>Perm</th><th>Email</th>
    <th>Date</th></tr>";
    // print the results
    while(list($id,$name,$pass,$perm,$email,$date) = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr><td>$id</td><td>$name</td><td>$pass</td><td>$perm</td><td>$email</td>
        <td>$date</td></tr>";
    }
    echo '</table>';


$query = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS numrows FROM news";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, couldn\'t get count title=\"$page\"').mysql_error();

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$numrows = $row['numrows'];

$lastPage = ceil($numrows/$rowsPerPage);
$phpself = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];


if ($pageNum > 1)
{
    $page = $pageNum - 1;
    $prev = "<div class=\"paginationbtn floatleft\"><a href=\"$phpself?id=$rowid&amp;page=$page\">previous</a></div>";
    $first = " <a href=\"$phpself?page=1\" title=\"Page 1\">[First Page]</a> ";
}
else
{
    $prev = ' previous ';
    $first = ' [First Page] ';
}

if ($pageNum < $lastPage)
{
    $page = $pageNum + 1;

    $resultid = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM news");
    while($loopid=mysql_fetch_array($resultid))
    { 
        $rowid = $loopid['id'];
        $next = "  <div class=\"paginationbtn floatright\"><a href=\"$phpself?id=$rowid&amp;page=$page\" title=\"Page $page\">next</a></div> ";
    }
}

else
{
    $next = ' [Next] ';
}

echo $prev . " " . $next;
```

Comment: so you want to make a pagination?

Comment: MySQL functions are deprecated. Please consider switching over to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.php). Your query is also vulnerable to MySQL injection.

Comment: @madalinivascu only Previous and Next button

Comment: @WillParky93 not familiar with PDO, I have limited time to explore more about it. The code need to submit tomorrow. But I will learn it for the next. This code is the testing code I used for this forum only, I have my own code actually.

Comment: Really need help, hoping that some of you could provide me with some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the previous and next ids from the database

```
if ($pageNum > 1)
{
   //Get previous id using this query
   SELECT id FROM news LIMIT $previousRows-1, $rowsPerPage
}



if ($pageNum < $lastPage)
{
   //Get next id using this query
   SELECT id FROM news LIMIT $previousRows+1, $rowsPerPage
}
```

Comment: It's works perfectly on previous and next button! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following sql query to get the next id,right now you are looping the news table and your next button will always have the same value

```
    if ($pageNum < $lastPage)
    {
        $page = $pageNum + 1;

        $resultid = mysql_query("select id from news where id = (select min(id) from news where id > ".$_GET['id'].")");
        while($loopid=mysql_fetch_array($resultid))
        { 
            $rowid = $loopid['id'];
            $next = "  <div class=\"paginationbtn floatright\"><a href=\"$phpself?id=$rowid&amp;page=$page\" title=\"Page $page\">next</a></div> ";
        }
$prevresultid = mysql_query("select id from news where id = (select max(id) from news where id < ".$_GET['id'].")");
        while($loopid=mysql_fetch_array($prevresultid))
        { 
            $rowid = $loopid['id'];
            $prev= "  <div class=\"paginationbtn floatleft\"><a href=\"$phpself?id=$rowid&amp;page=$page\" title=\"Page $page\">next</a></div> ";
        }
    }
```

Note: you will need mysqli and prepared statements to secure your code

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but how if I have some deleted content? I'm trying to put `where status='published'`, e.g `select id from news where status='published' and id = (select min(id) from news where id > '".$_GET['id']."')` but the deleted content still showing out.

Comment: @Eelyn put the status in the subquery

Comment: `select id from news where id = (select min(id) from news  where status='published' and id > '".$_GET['id']."')`

Comment: `select id from news where id = (select min(id) from news where status='published' and id > '".$_GET['id']."')` The deleted content still showing out, although the URL id is correct. Am I write correctly?

Comment: what content? the query return only the id

Comment: add you where here `$query = "SELECT * FROM news  where status='published'  LIMIT $previousRows, $rowsPerPage";`

Comment: opps, sorry. My fault. I didn't notice about that! How about previous button?

Comment: to the previous you do `$resultid = mysql_query("select id from news where id = (select max(id) from news where id < ".$_GET['id'].")");`

Comment: Tried `max(id)`, but the URL shows the wrong ID number. Kindly check https://image.ibb.co/kvaayG/joyden2.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158362/discussion-between-eelyn-and-madalinivascu).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set pagination than no need of next id it will mange by query only . and in query we change only offset .
for e.g each page display 3 records so our limit is 3 
now if we on first page than our fetch record query is(on first page offset is always 0)
so offset is 0 and limit is 3
SELECT fieldName FROM tableName LIMIT offset,limit

for second page now current offset is 3 so

prev is  current_offset minus limit (3-3) so prev offset is 0
next is  current_offset plus limit (3+3) so next offset is 6

now in 3rd page current offset is 6

prev is  current_offset minus limit (6-3) so prev offset is 3
next is  current_offset plus limit (6+3) so next offset is 9

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```html
<?php
$rowsPerPage = 1;

if(isset($_GET['page']))
{
    $pageNum= $_GET['page'];
}
else
{
    $pageNum = 1;
}

// preceding rows
$previousRows =($pageNum - 1) * $rowsPerPage;

$query = "SELECT * FROM news LIMIT $previousRows, $rowsPerPage";//offset,limit
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error couldn\'t get the data').mysql_error();

    echo "<table border=1>\n";
    echo "<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Password</th><th>Perm</th><th>Email</th>
    <th>Date</th></tr>";
    // print the results
    while(list($id,$name,$pass,$perm,$email,$date) = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr><td>$id</td><td>$name</td><td>$pass</td><td>$perm</td><td>$email</td>
        <td>$date</td></tr>";
    }
    echo '</table>';


$query = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS numrows FROM news";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, couldn\'t get count title=\"$page\"').mysql_error();

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$numrows = $row['numrows'];

$lastPage = ceil($numrows/$rowsPerPage);
$phpself = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];


if ($pageNum > 1)//current page > 1
{
    $page = $pageNum - 1;
    $prev = "<div class=\"paginationbtn floatleft\"><a href=\"$phpself?id=$rowid&amp;page=$page\">previous</a></div>";
    $first = " <a href=\"$phpself?page=1\" title=\"Page 1\">[First Page]</a> ";
}
else
{
    $prev = ' previous ';
    $first = ' [First Page] ';
}

if ($pageNum < $lastPage)
{
    $page = $pageNum + 1;
    $next_row=$previousRows+1;
    $resultid = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM news LIMIT $next_row,1");
    while($loopid=mysql_fetch_array($resultid))
    { 
        $rowid = $loopid['id'];
        $next = "  <div class=\"paginationbtn floatright\"><a href=\"$phpself?id=$rowid&amp;page=$page\" title=\"Page $page\">next</a></div> ";
    }
}

else
{
    $next = ' [Next] ';
}

echo $prev . " " . $next;
```